# Three.js - How to improve the look and feel of 3D models in Three.JS

Tags: three.js, lighting

I was wondering why the model I rendered in my sample three.js (https://codeshare.io/5Z8RXg) looks very poor in terms of rendering compared with this model in a sophisticated 3D visualisation tool (I keep the name of the product).

How I can improve the quality of my 3D modelling? I understand lighting and light mapping are very important. But could you please advise on all important parameters to achieve this. Please dont give just general answers.

Thanks.

This is the code for the first image: https://codeshare.io/5Z8RXg

[image: simple rendering]

[image: Professionally rendering]

Comment: specifically the term you are looking for is "light baking"

Comment: like pailhead said, to get the look you posted you need [baked lightmaps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/how-do-you-bake-ambient-occlusion-for-a-model), sometimes called ambient occlusion. You'll likely need to do this in your modeling package. It will generate textures have have the many of the shadows baked in. Then you also need to turn on shadows in three

Comment: Thanks @pailhead. I baked the model in Blender. How can I bring the baked model into three.js?